# mongodb(x86) stopping service while insert

Tags: java, mongodb, insert, windows-services, mongodb-java

I have large arrayList. I am trying to insert all list to mongodb by dividing 1000 items per inserting.
But MongoDb service stops after inserting arround 900 000  records.

I am getting this error:

```
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Type: System.IO.IOException
Stack:    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonBuffer.LoadFrom(Stream stream, Int32 count)
   at MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonBuffer.LoadFrom(Stream stream)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage[TDocument](BsonBinaryReaderSettings readerSettings, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursorEnumerator`1.GetReply(MongoConnection connection, MongoRequestMessage message)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursorEnumerator`1.GetFirst()
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursorEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabase.GetCollectionNames()
   at MangoUI.MCollections.GetAll(String db)
   at MangoUI.MCollections.Get(String db)
   at MangoUI.ComNavTree.ExpandMe(MTreeNode expand)
   at MangoUI.ComNavTree.tree_BeforeExpand(Object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)


An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Type: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Stack:    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

My code is like this. What should I do?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package yaz;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import mudi.BOB;
import mudi.BOBM;
import mudi.Employee;
import tmsf.TMSF;

/**
 *
 * @author mkilic
 */
public class MongoDbInsert {

    static List<BOBM> bobmList = new ArrayList<BOBM>();
    static Mongo mongo; 
    static DB db;
    static DBCollection employeeCollection;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

        mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
        db = mongo.getDB("TestDB");
         employeeCollection  = db.getCollection("tblBOB");

        for (int j = 0; j < 13000; j++) {
            bobmList = new ArrayList<BOBM>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                BOBM bobm = new BOBM();
                bobm.setB01("aaaaaaaaaaaaa1");
                bobm.setB02("aaaaaaaaaaaaa2");
                bobm.setB03("aaaaaaaaaaaaa3");
                bobm.setB04("aaaaaaaaaaaaa4");
                bobm.setB05("aaaaaaaaaaaaa5");
                bobm.setB06("aaaaaaaaaaaaa6");
                bobm.setB07("aaaaaaaaaaaaa7");
                bobm.setB08("aaaaaaaaaaaaa8");
                bobm.setB09("aaaaaaaaaaaaa9");
                bobm.setB10("aaaaaaaaaaaaa10");
                bobm.setB11("aaaaaaaaaaaaa11");
                bobm.setB12("aaaaaaaaaaaaa12");
                bobm.setB13("aaaaaaaaaaaaa13");
                bobm.setB14("aaaaaaaaaaaaa14");
                bobm.setB15("aaaaaaaaaaaaa15");
                bobm.setB16("aaaaaaaaaaaaa16");
                bobm.setB17("aaaaaaaaaaaaa17");
                bobm.setB18("aaaaaaaaaaaaa18");
                bobm.setB19("aaaaaaaaaaaaa19");
                bobm.setB20("aaaaaaaaaaaaa20");
                bobm.setB21("aaaaaaaaaaaaa21");
                bobm.setB22("aaaaaaaaaaaaa22");
                bobm.setB23("aaaaaaaaaaaaa23");
                bobm.setB24("aaaaaaaaaaaaa24");
                bobmList.add(bobm);
                bobm = null;
            }
            insertMon(bobmList);
            bobmList = null;
        }
   mongo.close();
    }

    public static void insertMon(List<BOBM> list) throws UnknownHostException {

        for (Iterator<BOBM> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            BOBM bobm = it.next();
            employeeCollection.insert(bobm);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any Mongo server log that offers more debugging info?

Comment: Log file is empty because of MongoDb service was stoped.

Comment: Are you still seeing this error? I would expect there could be more information in the MongoDB log. You could try setting the [`logappend`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#logappend) option in your MongoDB configuration so the log file is not overwritten when the process restarts.